# Docker single build artifact for multiple images

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

I have two .NET projects which depend on the same DLL. Currently, this DLL is building for each of the projects. Is there a way to build it once and share it among the Dockerfiles?

Comment: P.S.: I am relatively new to Docker and because of that my question might be unclear, please let me know in the comments and I'll edit it. Thanks

Comment: Do the two .NET projects build at the same time?

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen, yes.

Comment: Look into multistage builds then.  First stage builds the DLL only, two next steps build on that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should create the following docker image files:

1. DLL dockerfile: it builds the DLL and stores the DLL.
2. Project A fockerfile: it inherits from then "DLL dockerfile" and uses the DLL built from the base image.
3. Project B dockerfile: same as for the "Project A".

Comment: "it builds the DLL and stores the DLL", I pretty much thought like that, but "stores the DLL" is the most unclear for me. How I can do that? Thanks

Comment: Store = `COPY your.dll /app-folder`.